# Powershell API web service calls

Tags: web-services, api, powershell, powershell-2.0

So first of all I am fairly new to PowerShell (within the last year) I understand a lot of it now, however now API calls are new to me.

I have figure out how to make API calls with web calls that do not require any values. Or ones that don't require an array of values. Such as: $BSSPrincipalManagementWSP.ReadAccount("1_V4-0119341")

Returns everything I want. But If I get into something fancy like the web call for $BSSPrincipalManagementWSP.UpdateAccountValues the first variable is the account external ID, but the second variable required is the accountValues, in an array.

I have tried something like this to accomplish it:

```
function Update-AccountValues

(

    [string]$accountExternalId,

    [array]$accountValues = @(Import-Csv -Path $ImportPath)

)

{

    $accountValues

    $BSSPrincipalManagementWSP.UpdateAccountValues($accountExternalId, $accountValues)

}



Update-AccountValues "1_V4-0119341"
```

But I get the following error:

```
Cannot convert argument "accountValues", with value: "System.Object[]", for     "UpdateAccountValues" to type "BSSPrincipalManagementNS.AccountValue[]": "Cannot convert value 

"@{Key=ScreenSaverTimeoutMinutes; Value=60}" to type "BSSPrincipalManagementNS.AccountValue". Error: "Cannot convert the "@{Key=ScreenSaverTimeoutMinutes; Value=60}" value of type 

"System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject" to type "BSSPrincipalManagementNS.AccountValue".""

At C:\Users\Matt Bergeron\AppData\Local\Temp\ff88f967-9d7c-4f6f-a424-212298a69655.ps1:61 char:2

+     $BSSPrincipalManagementWSP.UpdateAccountValues($accountExternalId, $accountValu ...

+    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException

+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument
```

I thought I was passing it "an array of accountValue objects" as it asked for.

All that is in the CSV file is 2 columns, 1 listed as Keys and the other listed as Values. These are named exactly as the OSS/BSS CHM file called them.

Can anyone else tell where I went wrong? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You API is expecting the value to be of a specific type `BSSPrincipalManagementNS.AccountValue[]`.  You need to find another API call where you can create instances of `BSSPrincipalManagementNS.AccountValue` and put them in an array.  Then call the original API with that array.

Comment: Like I said, I'm really new to API calls, do you have any recommendations on where to look for the other API to create the array? thank you for your input.

Comment: @chamele0n Sorry but I don't know anything about this API.  Can you contact whoever created the web service to get a pointer to docs?